# Not passing Parameter to URL in IONIC

Tags: json, forms, url, ionic-framework, get

Im trying to get Parameters from a Home page  This is Form CODE.Data already passing to the function(select).

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="Select(f.value)">
 <ion-input placeholder="Student ID" type="text" name="Studentid" ngModel></ion-input>
<ion-input placeholder="Subject ID" type="text" name="Subjectid" ngModel></ion-input>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

This is my ts code

```
export class HomePage {

users:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public http :Http) {
  }
```

This is my function. The values are passing from the form not getting to url parameters but in console.log  values are printing.

```
Select(data) {

      var stuid= data.Studentid;
      var subid = data.Subjectid;
if(stuid && subid != null)
{
  console.log(stuid);
  console.log(subid);

      this.http.get("http://localhost:8100/Service1.svc/RestService/Checkstudent/{0}/{1}",stuid,subid)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.users = res;
      }, (err) => {
        alert("failed loading json data");
      });
}
    }
```

This is the result of the executing function in network log

> Request URL:
>   http://localhost:8100/Service1.svc/RestService/Checkstudent/%7B0%7D/%7B1%7D

This error also so showing in the start

[image: This error also so showing in start]

> Expected 1-2 arguments,but got 3
>   in line       this.http.get("http://localhost:8100/Service1.svc/RestService/Checkstudent/{0}/{1}",stuid,subid)

Comment: well the error is self explanatory. what are you trying to do with the url in your http call?

Comment: get data to the page  Home As  List

Comment: already done it but manually assign data to the URL Like this (http://localhost:8100/Service1.svc/RestService/Checkstudent/D51E8459/CNET343) but i need to get those parameters using form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http.get()` takes max of 2 parameters: the url and the RequestOptions consisting of headers.

If you want to add url parameters in the string, use backticks:

```
this.http.get(`http://localhost:8100/Service1.svc/RestService/Checkstudent/${stuid}/${subid}`)
```

This is called [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Wowww its worked  Broooo :D Thank you So much. i spend 5 hours on this to figure out Thank  you :)

Comment: with ur code i just replace this  ` to  ' this then its not worked. just replace ur code its worked!! .  i cant understand can you explain it

Comment: One is single quote the other is backticks. The key below escape key. Its js syntax to embed variables in string literals. Check the link in the answer

Comment: Thank you :)  so much i understood it :)